# SPF and IPv6 fails even if the reverse DNS is created

Tags: email, spf, reverse-dns

When sending mails to Gmail I get this error

> Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of test@domain.com does not
>   designate 2a01:4f8:xxx::2 as permitted sender)
>   client-ip=2a01:4f8:xxx::2;

When I test the IPv6 `2a01:4f8:xxx::2` reverse DNS (https://network-tools.webwiz.net/reverse-dns.htm) it maps to the correct host `smtp.domain.com`

## SPF record

```
v=spf1 a mx -all
```

## DNS records

- A record `smtp` targeting the IPv4 `88.133.xxx.xxx`
- MX record targeting `smtp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you lack an AAAA record for `smtp` with content `2a01:4f8:xxx::2`.

Comment: Correct. In addition to the _reverse_ DNS you also need the _forward_ DNS.

Comment: not so useful ansver